# Error ITMS-90279: Invalid Bundle

Tags: xcode, sparkle

I'm getting this error when trying to submit an app to the Mac App Store. Is Sparkle configured incorrectly, or just completely disallowed from inclusion in the app?

[image]

Comment: Having Sparkle in a Mac App Store app is redundant, as the app store has its own update mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application using Sparkle violates the [Mac App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/mac/), and will never stand a chance passing the review. Specifically:

> 2.21 Apps may not use update mechanisms outside of the App Store

And since Sparkle is very widely popular, Xcode is made to automatically detect its existence, and reject it before it is submitted for human reviews.

If you only wish to distribute your application via the App Store, you should remove Sparkle from the project. If you wish to provide both the App Store and non-App Store versions, you will need to make two different builds, and include Sparkle only for the one that won’t be submitted to the App Store.

Comment: Yep, it's straight up blacklisted. Removing it allows submission. Thanks!